# How do I check for vowels in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm supposed to write a function that takes a character (i.e. a string of length 1) and returns true if it is a vowel, false otherwise. I came up with two functions, but don't know which one is better performing and which way I should prefer. The one with RegEx is way simpler but I am unsure whether I should try to avoid using RegEx or not?

**Without RegEx:**

```
function isVowel(char) {
  if (char.length == 1) {
    var vowels = new Array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u");
    var isVowel = false;

    for (e in vowels) {
      if (vowels[e] == char) {
        isVowel = true;
      }
    }

    return isVowel;
  }
}
```

**With RegEx:**

```
function isVowelRegEx(char) {
  if (char.length == 1) {
    return /[aeiou]/.test(char);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what is your function supposed to return if the string length isn't 1?

Comment: [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-for-loop)

Comment: I'm not sure what the context is, but you will have problems dealing with different languages. How would you treat the letter " ë " for example in the name Zoë? It's still a vowel even if it existed on it's own.

Can you give more information?

Answer (score 55):

[benchmark](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-for-loop)

I think you can safely say a for loop is faster.

I do admit that a regexp looks cleaner in terms of code. If it's a real bottleneck then use a for loop, otherwise stick with the regular expression for reasons of "elegance"

If you want to go for simplicity then just use

```
function isVowel(c) {
    return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(c.toLowerCase()) !== -1
}
```

Comment: in Firefox 4 indexOf() is the fastest. BTW, cool benchmark site for testing!!

Comment: @Max interesting how firefox optimised index of on strings.

Comment: [It's far, far faster to just have an explicit `if` statement that checks `char === 'a' || char === 'e'` etc](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-for-loop/2) -- whoa except not in Firefox!!

Comment: I see. It's sometimes twice as fast as the regex. Interesting! :)

Comment: @Pointy only in crankshaft. string index is more optimised in jagermonkey and in IE8 index & expression are neck & neck. Tbh at this level your optimising for specific javascript engines. Just stick to something that's short, readable and maintenable. Also nitro prefers index. I don't have carakan around to test though.

Comment: @Raynos totally agree - unless it's some gigantic page full of text to be processed or something, and the function is going to be called zillions of times, any of the implementations are perfectly fine. If it **is** going to be called zillions of times, well, I'd wonder whether some fundamental aspect of the problem might be reconsidered :-)

Comment: @Pointy Then we get to do all kinds of javascript engine sniffing to micro optimise the hell out of this :D

Answer (score 32):

Lots of answers available, speed is irrelevant for such small functions unless you are calling them a few hundred thousand times in a short period of time. For me, a regular expression is best, but keep it in a closure so you don't build it every time:

Simple version:

```
function vowelTest(s) {
  return (/^[aeiou]$/i).test(s);
}
```

More efficient version:

```
var vowelTest = (function() {
  var re = /^[aeiou]$/i;
  return function(s) {
    return re.test(s);
  }
})();
```

Returns `true` if `s` is a single vowel (upper or lower case) and `false` for everything else.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the more efficient version? i ran it and it works just like the simple version but (1)why is it considered more efficient? (2)what does the outermost parentheses signify? on first look i would've said that this is a function that returns a function (the closure(?) function(s)). do the outer (...)() change anything?

Comment: I consider it more efficient because the regular expression is created once and reused rather than created every time. The enclosing "()" turn a function declaration into a function expression so the name can be omitted. It could also start with `!` but grouping also has semantics that say "all of this belongs togther" whereas "!" seems to be saying "not something…". The trailing "()" causes the function to be called and can be inside or outside the closing ")", many prefer inside (semantics again).

Comment: You started saying speed is irrelevant, why using closures would be considered a significant optimization?

Comment: @JoséSalgado—because sometimes speed *does* matter. :-)

Answer (score 9):

cycles, arrays, regexp... for what? It can be much quicker :)

```
function isVowel(char)
{
    return char === 'a' || char === 'e' || char === 'i' || char === 'o' || char === 'u' || false;
}
```

Comment: This will break if char is a string.

Comment: it will return false if char.length > 1 and i think this is correct

Comment: `String.prototype.index` is faster in firefox then this. Also this is ugly.

Comment: @Raynos Not as ugly as cycles (for this problem) :) And yes, maybe index faster. I've post this just for fun and another solution.

Comment: @Emmerman it's a simplistic solution correct. And it's fun :)

Comment: Why does this function end in `|| false`?

Comment: Regex is iteratively faster, and even putting the vowels in an array and running includes on it against the character is faster and cleaner than this.

Answer (score 6):

```
function findVowels(str) {
  return str.match(/[aeiou]/ig);
}

findVowels('abracadabra'); // 'aaaaa'
```

Basically it returns all the vowels in a given string.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would define it this way:

```
function isVowel( chr ){ return 'aeiou'.indexOf( chr[0].toLowerCase() ) !== -1 }
```

You could also use `['a','e','i','o','u']` and skip the length test, but then you are creating an array each time you call the function. (There are ways of mimicking this via closures, but those are a bit obscure to read)

Comment: The regular expression is nicer and not noticably slower `/[aeiou]/.text(chr.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 4):

This is a rough RegExp function I would have come up with (it's untested)

```
function isVowel(char) {
    return /^[aeiou]$/.test(char.toLowerCase());
}
```

Which means, `if (char.length == 1 && 'aeiou' is contained in char.toLowerCase()) then return true`.

Answer (score 4):

I kind of like this method which I think covers all the bases:

```
const matches = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
return matches ? matches.length : 0;
```

Comment: i think you have a typo on your match. `const matches = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);`

Answer (score 2):

```
function isVowel(char)
{
  if (char.length == 1)
  {
    var vowels = "aeiou";
    var isVowel = vowels.indexOf(char) >= 0 ? true : false;

    return isVowel;
  }
}
```

Basically it checks for the index of the character in the string of vowels. If it is a consonant, and not in the string, `indexOf` will return -1.

Comment: @Raynos, one could argue, is it necessary to return `undefined`?

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman one could argue that `isVowel` on a string of length > 1 is undefined behaviour and should therefore validly return `undefined`. What does it mean for `aa` to _not_ be a vowel?

Answer (score 2):

Basically it returns all the vowels in a given string.

```
function vowels(s) {
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

  for(let v of s) {
    if(vowels.includes(v))
        console.log(v);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I did it, on the first occurrence of a vowel in any given word it breaks out of the loop and returns true.

```
const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"];

function isVowel(word) {
    let result = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (vowels.includes(word[i])) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: After testing, it seems the `break` is unnecessary, but I'm no expert, I started recently learning js so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simplified version using [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). My technique is similar to [@Kunle Babatunde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488028/how-do-i-check-for-vowels-in-javascript/50843085#50843085).

```js
const isVowel = (char) => ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(char);

console.log(isVowel("o"), isVowel("s"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  //function to find vowel
const vowel = (str)=>{
  //these are vowels we want to check for
  const check = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
  //keep track of vowels
  var count = 0;
  for(let char of str.toLowerCase())
  {
    //check if each character in string is in vowel array
    if(check.includes(char)) count++;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(vowel("hello there"));
```

Comment: this returns the total number of vowels.