# Can anyone help me with this simple code?

Tags: javascript

```
function isVowel(char){

    if(typeof char == 'string' && char.length > 1){
        console.log('not a char');
        return 'not a char';
    } else {
        if (char.toLowerCase() === ('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u')){
            console.log(char, true);
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log(char, false);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

document.writeln(isVowel('a'));
document.writeln(isVowel('e'));
document.writeln(isVowel('l'));
```

the result is: true, false, false;

it should be: true, true, false;

Can anyone help me why this is happening?

I'm just barely learning JavaScript...

**Also, is there any way to refactor this code? I don't want to be repeating myself for every new condition..**

Comment: why the downvote? i'm just barely learning javascript..

Comment: I think the downvote is due to the question title... "Can anyone help me?" does not describe your problem... you see?

Comment: @J.Bruni what would have been a better title?

Comment: "Function to determine if char is a vowel is not working" may be not the best title, but I think it is already a little better.

Comment: @J.Bruni yeah, that actually sounds better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u')`  is equal to `"a"`

To confirm the above, just try it using the console, or:

```
console.log(('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'));
```

My suggestion:

```
' aeiou'.indexOf(char) > 0
```

Complete version:

```
function isVowel(char){

    if(typeof char == 'string' && char.length > 1){
        console.log('not a char');
        return 'not a char';
    } else {
        if (' aeiou'.indexOf(char) > 0){
            console.log(char, true);
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log(char, false);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

document.writeln(isVowel('a'));
document.writeln(isVowel('e'));
document.writeln(isVowel('l'));
```

Refactored version:

```
function isVowel(char)
{
    return ((typeof char == 'string') && (char.length == 1) && ('aeiou'.indexOf(char.toLowerCase()) != -1));
}
```

Comment: @paislee: I have not swiped your idea, if you mean the "indexOf" usage; only when I was about to add the "refactored version", I improved the code by using the `-1` info from your comment

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate `||`s like this:

```
char.toLowerCase() === 'a'
|| char.toLowerCase() === 'e'
|| char.toLowerCase() === 'i'
|| char.toLowerCase() === 'o'
|| char.toLowerCase() === 'u'
```

instead of like this:

```
char.toLowerCase() === ('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u')
```

Here's a jsFiddle of the above:

- http://jsfiddle.net/sXbBh/

Comment: thanks.. just wondering.. what would be the best way of doing this instead of repeating myself over and over again?

Comment: [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science)) is a structure suited for this. JS doesn't have them, but you can simulate with objects (i.e. `{}`) easily, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript. For small number of these, looping over array should be just fine - i.e. make an array `var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']` and then use `for` to go through each of the values and check. Or don't reinvent and just use what's already been done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488028/best-way-of-checking-for-vowels-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (/[aeiou]/.test(char.toLowerCase())){
      // ...
    } else {
      // ...
    }
```

Comment: be warned of `regex` solutions is almost always slower than `indexOf` algorithm. This can be a issue inside critical loops.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
if (char.toLowerCase() === ('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'))
```

Equality operators don't "distribute", you'll have to test the input against each possibility independently. A concise solution might be

```
if ("aeiou".indexOf(char.toLowerCase()) + 1) {
    console.log(char, true);
    return true;
}
```

- [Array.indexOf()<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: `indexOf` finds the location of the search string. if it can't be found it returns `-1`. It's doing all the work for you == simpler code.

Comment: @paislee: `"aeiou".indexOf("a")` will return `0` (zero) and evaluate to `false` - your code above will give wrong results