# Setting up a if else function that detects if it is a vowel

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am new to JavaScript and I know I did something wrong because I keep getting `true` as a result. Can someone please point out my mistake? Thanks in advance.

```
function checkForVowel(x){
   if(x == "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"){
       document.write("true");
   }else{
       document.write("false");
   }
}

checkForVowel("n");
```

Comment: Take a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488028/best-way-of-checking-for-vowels-in-javascript there are many ways to check for a vowels

Answer (score 11):

JavaScript's comparison operator isn't magic; you'll need to do each comparison separately. You can check for "any of these" using a logical OR, `||`:

```
if(x == "a" || x == "e" || x == "i" || x == "o" || x == "u")
```

Or, since you have many single-character strings, you can make use of `indexOf`. But the above might be easier to understand if you're just starting out.

```
if(x.length === 1 && 'aeiou'.indexOf(x) > -1)
```

As for the reason you keep getting true, it's that `,` is actually an operator in JavaScript, mainly invented to confuse people<sup>1</sup>. It evaluates its left side, then evaluates its right side, and returns the right side. So your expression boils down like this:

```
if(x == "a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
if("e", "i", "o", "u")
if("i", "o", "u")
if("o", "u")
if("u")
```

Which is a truthy value.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Not actually.</sub>

Comment: You should consider explaining why it returns `true` instead of `false`.

Comment: Better still would be `if(typeof x === "string" && x.length === 1 && 'aeiou'.indexOf(x) > -1)`

Comment: Not hugely important in this instance, but still better, [would prevent this](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/DZvHn/)

Comment: @Xotic750: I’m a fan of duck typing, so if somebody does that, I hope they have a really good reason. =D But thanks for the tip, could be useful!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the code is a lot cleaner to test against a data structure than use lots of `if/else` code.  Which is faster may depend upon the specific browser engine and how many comparisons you have.  This one looks to see if the string is present in a string of vowels:

```
var vowels = "aeiou";

function checkForVowel(x) {
    return(vowels.indexOf(x.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
}
```

This one tests to see if the test char is in a javascript object which isn't needed here, but is another interesting way to test if something is in a set:

```
var vowels = {a: true, e: true, i: true, o: true, u: true};

function checkForVowel(x) {
    return(x.toLowerCase() in vowels);
}
```

Comment: -1. Not even close. 83 million ops/sec for multiple `||`s and comparisons, versus 3 million ops/sec for `in`. http://jsperf.com/checking-using-object-key-lookup-vs-or

Comment: Oh, and the second revision shows that `indexOf`, at least on a string, is still faster than `in`. Plus `in` is less concise and less semantic, and still only works for string keys. Sorry, but this is no good.

Comment: Better ;) You might also want to note that the method will treat anything attached to `Object.prototype` as accurate. Not that it matters for vowels, but still... `'valueOf' in vowels`

Comment: @minitech - but the specific question here is characters only so either of these would work just fine (because they are just characters).  If you prefer to write your code with a compound comparison, that's fine with me.  I generally prefer other options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but no one suggested this. `:/`

```
function checkForVowel(x){
    document.write(/[aeiou]/i.test(x));   //Clearly this is even simpler than
}                                         // other methods.
```

Or

```
function checkForVowel(x){
   if(x.search(/[aeiou]/i) != -1){
       document.write("true");
   }else{
       document.write("false");
   }
}
```