# JavaScript Strip Vowels

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am trying to strip vowels in a string. I know I should be using `str.replace` but I am baffled on how to get it into a span.

This is more of less what i am looking to do:

Write a JavaScript function that takes in a string `s` and returns the string which is equivalent to `s` but with all ASCII vowels removed. EX: `(“Hello World”)` returns: `"Hll wrld"`

Please help!

Comment: Here ya go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488028/best-way-of-checking-for-vowels-in-javascript - using the search is an awesome way of finding out stuff

Comment: To get it into a span, you could use either jQuery or document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = whatever, where id is the id of your span and whatever is your modified string, as per the answers others gave below.

Answer (score 58):

`.replace(/[aeiou]/ig,'')` is all you need.

Answer (score 30):

To replace vowels you can use a simple regular expression:

```
function removeVowels(str) {
  return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '');
}
```

As for the part about getting it into a span, not 100% sure what you mean, but maybe something like this:

```
<span id="mySpan">Hello World!</span>
<script>
  var span = document.getElementById('mySpan');
  span.innerHTML = removeVowels(span.innerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: May I know what does `gi` in
`(/[aeiou]/gi, '')`means?

Comment: @Hunter IIRC the `g` is for global and the `i` is for insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

`string.replaceAll("[aeiou]\\B", "")`