# How to strip a hebrew string from its vowels?

Tags: javascript, string, hebrew

Im developing an app using vowels in hebrew. 
for example, חָלָק 
wanted ouput: חלק

what is the best why to do so?

Comment: found a solution:
`const stripVowels = rawString =>
  rawString.replace(/[\u0591-\u05C7]/g, '').trim();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Hebrew vowels, but you can adapt this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13829405/3029422)

```js
function removeVowels(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\u0061\u0041\u0065\u0046\u0069\u0049\u006f\u004F\u0075\u0055]/g, '');
}

console.log(removeVowels("Remove Vowels from this text !"));
```

Comment: I think the title was a rhetorical question. He answered it himself in his question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's just a matter of building the list of vowels characters in unicode notation for the desired language