# multiple conditions for same variables in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm just starting in coding, I'm trying to make a function that take a string as parameter and remove vowels from it, then return same string without vowels.
I do something like this.

```
var frase = "Hi how are you"

function removeVowels(frase) {
  var letras = frase.split("")
  
  for (var i = 0; i < letras.lenght; i++){
    if(letras[i] == "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A","E","I", "O", "U"){
            continue;
    }
     else{
      frase += letras[i]
      document.write(letras[i])
    }

    
  } 
  return frase;
  
}

var sinVocales = removeVowels(frase)

document.write(sinVocales)
```

I tried in if condition like this with && and || (letras[i] == "a" || letras[i] == "e" || letras[i] == "i" ... etc ) and it doesn't work.
I think I have a problem when I try to implement the function!

Thanks!

Comment: Spelling of 'length'? `letras.lenght`.

Comment: You also have `str` but no declaration, i.e., `var str...`.

Comment: you have to check a e I o u, one by one, use case statement, and you are writing two time document.write,

Comment: yes sorry str should be "frase"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var frase = "Hi how are you"
sinVocales = frase.replace(/[aeiou]/ig, "")
console.log(sinVocales)
```

Comment: string variables in JavaScript have the `replace` method, which could accept a Regular Expression.
`/[aeiou]/ig` is a Regular Expression that tries to match either 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', and 'u' in the given string, and ignores the case.
So the second line in the code is to try to find all the vowels from `frase`, and replace them with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the regular expression `[aeiou]` to test for vowels.
2. You need to initialize the result string to return instead of returning the input.
3. You can use `for ... of` to loop over the characters of the string instead of `split`.

```js
var frase = "Hi how are you"

function removeVowels(frase) {
  var str = "";
  for(const ch of frase){
    if(!/[aeiou]/gi.test(ch)){
      str += ch;
    }
  } 
  return str;
}

var sinVocales = removeVowels(frase)

console.log(sinVocales)
```

Comment: You realize they're just learning, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to put the vowels (or any character you want to check for) into an array and then check each character to see if it's in the array. If not, add it to a result string.

Also, don't use `document.write()`, it's an ancient method that has very limited use cases.

```js
// Put all the vowels in an array
var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A","E","I", "O", "U"];
var frase = "Hi how are you";

function removeVowels(frase) {
  var result = "";

  // Loop through the string
  frase.split("").forEach(function(char){
    // Check the char to see if it's not the array
    if(vowels.indexOf(char) == -1){
      result += char; // Add the char to the result
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(removeVowels(frase));
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do is that, i found solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829289/javascript-strip-vowels)

```
function removeVowels(str) {
  return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '');
}
```

But i try to answer with educational code.
First problem is the syntax in "letras.lenght" right code is "letras.length".
But we can do better, with pre existing function in JS.

In this code

```
  function removeVowels() {
    var frase = "Hi how are you";
    var letras = frase.split("");
    let str = "";
    const voweles = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"];
    for (var i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
      if (voweles.indexOf(letras[i]) === -1) {
        str += letras[i];
      }
    }
    return str;
  }
```

I created an array with the list of vowels, and i search if the specific word in the string "letras", corrispond to an exsisting value inside array, i check that with function indexOf, return index of founded element or -1 if there isn't.

Comment: really thanks! I appreciate your explanation and your time! 

Answer (score 0):

Check this for removing the vowels [JavaScript Strip Vowels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829289/javascript-strip-vowels)

To learn about your code and why it isn't working:

1- You don't need to split your frase, on JS you can access a character on a string by it index.

frase[0] // will return "H"

So you can do

```
for (var i = 0; frase.lenght; i++){
    if(frase[i] === "X") { ... }
}
```

2- You can't make a if with multiple conditions separated by comma, you can use the AND operator &&

```
if (frase[i] === "X" && frase[i] === "Y")
```

3- removeVowels should return str, you're now returning frase again

Comment: really thanks! I appreciate your explanation !!! 