# How to write a function by outputting Vowels(str), which gets a random string as a parameter

Tags: javascript

I am doing an exercise which method outputs should be all vowels (a, e, i, o, u, y) in the string. Any suggestions?

```
var letters = "abcdeiforusy"; 
var len = randint(12) + 10; 
var word = ""; 

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){ 
    word += letters.charAt(randint(letters.length)); 
    var vowels=a
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to output all vowels (in order) that occur? Or all vowels in the order they occur in. E.g. if I input `stackoverflow` do you want the output to be `aeo` or `aoeo`?

Comment: Last time I checked..."y" was not a vowel.

Comment: This code makes no sense at all. Why is `len` random? Why is randomness involved here anyway? What is `a`?

Comment: Also, what's with the random functions (`len = randint`, `letters.charAt(randint(...))`?

Comment: Actually the requirement is like this:

Comment: The code itself is unfinished. The exercise needs student to figure out how to finish it and get the result as required

Comment: Here is the whole contents, not more:

Comment: Write a function outputVowels(str), which gets a random string as a parameter.  You can assume, that all letters in the string are in lower case.

For example, if the method is called with parameter value of "yabba dabba doo", it should output
y
a
a
a
a
o
o
var letters = "abcdeiforusy"; 
var len = randint(12) + 10; 
var word = ""; 

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){ 
    word += letters.charAt(randint(letters.length)); 
    var vowels=a
} 

document.writeln("The word is: " + word); 
outputVowels(word);

Comment: @series0ne It depends :) [When is “Y” a vowel?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10458/when-is-y-a-vowel)

Comment: According to the English gramer, it includes also "Y"

Comment: @Andreas, Well, I didn't see that coming. I stand corrected, sir! Thanks for sharing. :-)

Comment: Hello All. Tks! I am very happy that there is nobody voted down me this time. I learned from previous question that I should try to find from other sources also. Tks for all of your replies!

Comment: @Longway_togo Please remember to mark the correct answer as the accepted answer to your question, in case any of the given answers helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To **determine if a letter is a vowel**, you could use different approaches as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5488098/1264909). You can even find some [benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-for-loop) to compare their prerformance.

Then, your solution could look something like this (I have used the character set approach because it is probably easier to understand than the RegEx one, but both would work perfectly fine):

```
// Determine if a letter is vowel or not
function isVowel(c) {
    return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(c) !== -1
}

var str = "abcdeiforusy"; 
var len = str.length;
var vowelsInStr = "";

for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (isVowel(str[i])) {
        // Do something with the vowel, e.g. print it in the console
        console.log(str[i]);

        // Or add it to the array of vowels
        vowelsInStr += str[i];
    }
}

// Print the vowels array
console.log(vowelsInStr);
```

Comment: So to answer the actual question ("The exercise needs student to figure out how to finish it and get the result as required"): Post on StackOverflow and someone will get it for you.

Comment: Actually, I have not read the comment about the student requirement. But I guess at the end of the day learning is not about getting the answer, but being able to understand the solution so you can solve similar problems by yourself. Otherwise, you are not learning anything :$

Comment: Tks! That's what I am trying to do. But after tried so long time without result, I have to ask help from clever ones. Tks for understanding and your comments.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily with a regex:

```
function vowels(str){
    return str.replace(/[^aeiou]/gi,"");
}
```

This function will return unique vowels in an []:

```
function uniqueVowels(str){
    var vowelArr = [];
    var tmpVowels = str.replace(/[^aeiou]/gi,"").split("");
    for(var i = 0; i < tmpVowels.length; i++){
        if(vowelArr.indexOf(tmpVowels[i].toLowerCase()) == -1){
           vowelArr.push(tmpVowels[i].toLowerCase());
        }          
    }
    return vowelArr;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/DQq9R/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var s = 'gokul';
    var front, back, vowel = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if ((c == 'A') || (c == 'a') || (c == 'E') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'I') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'O') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'U') || (c == 'u')) {
            front = s.substring(0, i);
            vowel += c;
            back = s.substring(i + 1);
            s = front + back;
        }
    }
    console.log(vowel);
    console.log(s);
});
```

[Fiddle reference](http://jsfiddle.net/gokuldahal/VXM72/1/)