# Having trouble with an if/else statement

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to write a function called isVowel that takes a character (i.e. a string of length 1) and returns "true" if it is a vowel, uppercase or lowercase. The function should return "false" if the character is not a vowel.

This seems like it should work, but no matter what letter I enter, it returns "true." I've tried a bunch of different things, but I've hit a wall.

```
function isVowel(x){
  if (x === "a" || "A" || "e" || "E" || "i" || "I"|| "o" || "O" || "u" || "U" || "y" || "Y"){
    //console.log(x); // returns c
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
};
console.log(isVowel("c"));
```

Comment: `x === "a" || x === "A" || ....`

Comment: I'm sure you need x === on all posibilities. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: The `==` operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The `===` operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type === will simply return `false`. Both are equally quick.

Inculcate the habbit of using `===` comparision opeartor whenever the type and value of operands are strictly to be same. It will save from unwanted under the curtain issues.

Answer (score 7):

To simplify your code even further, you can create an array of valid values and simply check if the value they passed in is contained in the valid values list.

```js
function isVowel(x) {
  var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"];
  return vowels.indexOf(x.toLowerCase()) > -1;
};
console.log(isVowel("a"));
```

Comment: This is the most concise answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the improved and corrected version of your function:

Instead of checking all conditions for capital and small we first conver to small and then check using `x == a/e/i/o/u`.

```js
function isVowel(x)
{
  x = x.toLowerCase();
  if (x === "a" || x == "e" || x == "i" || x == "o" || x == "u"){
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
};
console.log(isVowel("a"));
```

A better approach suggested by @yBrodsky is:

```js
function isVowel(x)
{
  var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  
  return vowels.indexOf(x.toLowerCase()) != -1;
};
console.log(isVowel("a"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @CraigCarter There will be a tick next to every answer the community members have given you, You need to click on the tick next to the answer that was helpful to you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/[a|e|i|o|u]/i.test(YOURTEXTHERE)`.

Below is a single liner to accomplish this:

```js
var YOURTEXTHERE = 'b';

// check if it's vowel
if (/[a|e|i|o|u]/i.test(YOURTEXTHERE)) {
  console.log('vowel!');
}
else
  console.log('not vowel');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `||` operator is incorrect.  Your code is currently evaluating `x === "a"`, then `"A"` which is always a truthy value.  You either need to use a list of comparisons like this:

```
if (x === "a" || x === "A" || x === "o" || ...) {...}
```

Or something like this (much neater, and [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488028/how-do-i-check-for-vowels-in-javascript)):

```
if (['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(x.toLowerCase())) {...}
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please use the green check mark to let people know!

Answer (score 0):

You are only comparing x == "a", you need to have 
x=="A"||x=="o" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

***A clean version might be:***

```js
function isVowel(x) {
  return (['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'].indexOf(x.toLowerCase()) > -1);
};

console.log(isVowel("c"));
console.log(isVowel("a"));
console.log(isVowel("A"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're passing in a string with a length of `1` you could use `String.includes` for a simple comparison. No need for any arrays at all.

```js
function isVowel(x){
  return 'aeiouy'.includes( x.toLowerCase() );
};

console.log( isVowel("c") ); // false
console.log( isVowel("e") ); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a different approach and a cleaner solution may work better as follows.

```
function isVowel(character) {

  // Clean the character to eliminate errors with capital letters
  let cleanedChar = character.toLowerCase();

  // Check if the cleaned character which is now any lower case letter matches a vowel
  if (cleanedChar.match(/[aeiou]/g)) {
    // Return true if it does
    return true;
  }

  // return false if ever get to this point (it means the char was not a vowel)
  return false;
}

// Call isVowel function and pass it 'c'
console.log(isVowel('c'));
```